# how to use pattern.compile for the image src

Tags: java, android

how should i use the Pattern.compile for the img src :

i am using as 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("img src=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

but it doesn't give an image.

please help.

Comment: <img src="//img.indiaforums.com/person/320x240/0/0002-shah-rukh-khan.jpg?c=0qL4B1" class="img-responsive" alt="Shah Rukh Khan">. for this img src i need help how do i use the argument pattern.compile

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
(src=")+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/\.\?="]
```

This should give you the entire src property with its value. Then you can split/explode the resultant string on `"` and extract the image location.